# Meaning of 'to make a screen to' (1791 US)

Tags: meaning-in-context, history

Source: p 64, *RIGHTS OF MAN: Being An Answer To Mr. Burke’s Attack On The FRENCH REVOLUTION*, by Thomas Paine, 1791.
Paine's "Answer" above immediately follows:
[p 64, *The Revolution in France*](http://books.google.com/books?id=TtUuAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA64&dq=%22as+a+matter+of+right%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kI3HU56oHo7boATp74HoDw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22as%20a%20matter%20of%20right%22&f=false), by Edmund Burke, second edition (1790)

> It will always happen, when a thing is originally wrong, that amendments do not make it right, and it often happens that they do as much mischief one way as good the other : and such is the case here ; for if the one rashly declares war as a matter of right, and the other peremptorily with-holds the supplies as a matter of right, the remedy becomes as bad or worse than the disease. The one forces the nation to a combat, and the other ties its hands : But the more probable issue is, that the contrast will end in a collusion between the parties, and be **made a [screen](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/screen) to** both. [(Kindly transcribed by Sven Yargs)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/185566/50720)
>
> [screen (noun)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/screen) = 1.1. A thing providing concealment or protection

Am I right that Definition 1.1 applies here? What does the last sentence mean?
Does Paine mean that the collusion will conceal both parties? But (from?) what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right that Definition 1.1 (= A thing providing **conceal**ment or **protect**ion) applies here.

However, I see the "contrast" (and not the "collusion") being used as a screen to *conceal* the parties' collusion and *protect* them from public criticism/outcry that would arise from the discovery of their collusion.  The thinking being that the public wouldn't suspect that parties holding such contrasting views could ever agree to collude on the matter.